# How to integrate and start Datadog monitoring for Windows Apache web servers?

Tags: apache, webserver, monitoring, datadog

I need to integrate Datadog monitoring on Apache web servers which are on Windows servers. Is there a link/blog available detailing the same for Windows server specifically ? [I got a blog link from Datadog but it seems not to cover Windows servers.](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-apache-web-server-datadog/) Need it specifically for Windows servers.

Answer (score 0):

Window option available... Go to integration and  click on agents.. There is an option available windows ( left side ).. Click on windows then u get link..... Just copy the link and paste it on ur windows Server.... Then datadog starts monitoring... It takes 5 minutes to monitor